# Wordpress installation site folder move to the final site destination

Tags: server, directory, domain, testing

My client have a site : business.com

All the files of the old fashion site is there, images, video, html, css. i just made a folder called business.com/cms and installed wordpress here. FOr 2 month they write stuff, upload images and do there site in wp. Now it's time to lunch the site

The problem, all the images and page belong to business.com/cms not the root business.com. when i will remove the old site and put all the file from the cms folder at the root level, the site will miss a lot of thing, images and manually link pdf in text

How do you do that properly. Is itst possible to keep the site in /cms and used some .htaccess wizardry to make it look like root ?

HELP, need to lunch tomorrow !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your easiest solution here is to keep everything in your cms folder.

and follow this step found at
http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

This will keep all wordpress related files in the cms folder, but it will look like its running from the root, copy of index and some .htaccess wizardly as you call it :).
enjoy

> ### Using a pre-existing subdirectory install
>
> If you
>   already have WordPress installed in its own folder (i.e.
>   http://example.com/wordpress) then the steps are as follows:
>
> Go to the Generalpanel.
>
> In the box for **Site
>   address (URL):** change the address to the root directory's URL.
>   Example: http://example.com
>
> Click **Save
>   Changes**. (Do not worry about the error message and do not try to
>   see your blog at this point! You will probably get a message about
>   file not found.)
>
> Copy (NOT MOVE!) the index.php and
>   .htaccess files from the WordPress directory into the root
>   directory of your site (Blog address). The .htaccess file is
>   invisible, so you may have to set your FTP client to show hidden
>   files. If you are not using pretty permalinks, then you may not
>   have a .htaccess file. ***If you are running WordPress on
>   a Windows (IIS) server** and are using pretty permalinks, you'll
>   have a web.config rather than a .htaccess file in
>   your WordPress directory. As stated above, copy (don't move) the
>   index.php file to your root directory, but MOVE (DON'T COPY)
>   the web.config file to your root directory.*
>
> Open your root directory's index.php file in a text editor
>
> Change the following and save the file. Change the line that
>   says:
> require('./wp-blog-header.php');
> to the
>   following, using your directory name for the WordPress core
>   files:
> require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
>
> Login to your site. It should still be
>   http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/
>
> If you have
>   set up Permalinks, go to the Permalinks panel and update your
>   Permalink structure. WordPress will automatically update your
>   .htaccess file if it has the appropriate file permissions. If
>   WordPress can't write to your .htaccess file, it will display
>   the new rewrite rules to you, which you should manually copy into your
>   .htaccess file (in the same directory as the main
>   index.php file.)

Comment: How does this procedure affect wordpress updating in the futur ?

Comment: how do you mean? It just works as continued. Everything wordpress related stays in the folder, but all urls look like from root. Also when updating and adding new posts etc. I have all my wordpress websites like this just to keep things organised.

Comment: OK, nice it work for almost ALL but the root, instead of displaying the index.php "normal" page, it display : The page you were looking for is no longer available. because the index.php still send to the /cms page, that does not exist in the database of wp

Comment: did you change this bit:

Change the following and save the file. Change the line that says:
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
to the following, using your directory name for the WordPress core files:
require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');

Answer (score 0):

In `Settings > General` change *WordPress Address (URL)* to `http://business.com/cms` and *Site Address (URL)* to `http://business.com`.

The `index.php` file in root **(not in cms/ directory)**

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require('./cms/wp-blog-header.php');
```

Then move `cms/config.php` in the root to `config.php`.
And also move .htaccess from `cms/` directory to root.

Find the following lines if exist

```
RewriteBase /cms/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /cms/index.php [L]
```

and remove `cms/` string so you end up with the following

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Let me know if something went wrong.

Comment: How does this procedure affect wordpress updating in the futur ?

Comment: It doesn't, everything will work as expected, except when you want WordPress multisite.

Answer (score 0):

Wait...is it just me or no one thought suggesting a find & replace in the database might have fixed his problem..??

Find business.com/cms/ & replace it with "/" or "business.com"

And obviously moving the files from subfolder cms to the public_html...

All could have been done via ssh in seconds...

Comment: Some URLs are stored in serialized arrays. A simple replace would break those data completely.